# How can I open with PHP a SQlite Database and get the requestet information in a json document?

Tags: php, json, sqlite

I will use data form my database to use it later in a JS function. To get the data form the database I use sql request in php, then copy it in json but I dont get the value of my request.

I'm opening my database With following code:

```
<?php 
    $db = new PDO("sqlite:Playerbase.db");
    $info = $db ->query("SELECT Gamertag FROM player WHERE Highscore = 999");
    $info_json = json_encode($info);
    file_put_contents("Highscoreliste.json", $info_json);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">Highscoreliste();</script>';
    //I want to open the .json in this js funktion and use the informaton from the request.
    header("Location: index.html"); 
?>
```

But I dont get the real data in my .json, the value of the .json is:

```
{"queryString":"SELECT Gamertag FROM player WHERE Highscore = 999"}
```

Why am I just getting the Request copied in my .json and not the value of the request ? and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Take a look into the `query()` method of the PDO extension you are trying to use: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php   It returns a PDO object, not the result of the query. Take a look at the examples in that documentation, that should be easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find more infos, how to use PDO : https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Then here, there is a example how you can add JSON data into HTML, from Php :

```
<?php 
    $pdo = new PDO("sqlite:Playerbase.db");
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT Gamertag FROM player WHERE Highscore = 999");
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
    header("Location: index.html"); 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">const JSONDATA = ' . json_encode($data) . ';';
    echo 'Highscoreliste(JSONData);</script>';
?>
```

But a better ways is to make an Ajax request to fetch your data from your Backend.